# How do we find out values truncated in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle11g

If a column is of integer datatype and the average of values in that column is a decimal.In the output, the decimal part gets truncated, how do you make sure that the decimal part is not truncated

```
         25
       25.5
      30.1
     28.09
```

values inserted as

```
total_mark            number(10)
      25
      25
     30
     28
```

how will I find out the last 3 values got truncated

Comment: `column is of integer datatype` - when you say this then how come the dataset you showed in example have `decimal` parts ? Also, its not possible to have `decimal` part until you make your table to store it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about preserving decimal precision, then use a column type which supports that.  For example, if you wanted to preserve two decimal places, you could use `NUMBER(10,2)`, instead of `NUMBER(10)`, the latter which has no decimal precision.

Using `NUMBER(10)` you won't know which values got truncated, because in reality they all got truncated.  But it just so happens in the case of `25` that it had no non zero decimal component.

Comment: using CAST function?is it  a solution ?

Comment: Are you looking to _truncate_ your numbers, or to _find out_ if your data has been truncated?

Comment: to make sure that  the decimal part is not truncated